# Why might a landlord spend so much time at the house they're renting? How do I resolve this?

Tags: contract-law, landlord, tenant, rent, washington

Just moved into a new place... renting a single room with three other guys each renting their own rooms.  I've been here a month; they've been here for significantly longer.

The landlord spends far too much time here.  She doesn't live here. She isnt working on anything. She isn't doing paperwork regarding the property or tenants, not doing maintenance, etc.  In fact, all she does is performing yoga, reading, and taking up space.  She consumes utilities - which she doesn't contribute paying to.

She rigidly dictates the common areas, furniture, storage, etc; we've basically been exiled to the bedrooms. We can't even cook in the kitchen because she's always using the oven and stove at the most inopportune times of day, yet is willing to criticize us for our microwave and canned food diets we've been forced into.

And she comes over 3 or 4 days out of the week, for 6+ hours a day. Just loitering. In a place I'm paying her rent to have access to, to make my home.  I wonder if she'd do this if we four tenants were a single party and family of four renting the house.

I can't bring guests over because either she'd be in their faces, in the living room (which I've never been able to make my space and wouldn't feel comfortable in anyway), or she'd be spying on me outside my bedroom door "cleaning" and hounding me about overnight guests.

I know she technically owns the place.. but this is uncomfortable. And I feel like I'm paying way, way too much in rent for what I'm getting. No real house space. She wont let us use the empty garage for storage. She has keys to all of our bedrooms which I'd be more or less fine with if she weren't always here looking over my shoulder. I don't trust her to respect the sanctity of my bedroom, i.e. my privacy while I'm away.  It's like she doesn't trust her own tenants.

Is there anything I can do?  I'd be willing to breach my rental contract even and argue these points in court if I had to.  How do I approach someone about this disturbing behavior?  I feel like the landlord has breached contract by treating us this way, depriving us of the basic amenities that comes with renting a home, consuming resources without contributing to the bills, etc.

Comment: Where is this happening?

Comment: Lynnwood, WA, USA. Why?

Comment: Because the law is not the same all over the world. The answer will depend on location. Now, do you guys rent the whole house or just rooms?

Comment: Just the rooms.  I know, its a problem. Ive been renting rooms for over a decade and Ive never had a landlord act this way.

Comment: Would you be ok with this if the landlord did live there and was there 24/7?

Comment: Yes, actually. Thats how I lived with previous roommates/landlords. Was never a problem.  They had their own room and spent a fair portion of their time in it like everyone else.  They didnt just sit in the kitchen staring at the wall giving awkward smiles 6 hours a day until they finally decided to go to their own home for the night, just to come over and do it all over again the next day.

Comment: Landlord or no, you wouldnt want someone you didnt know coming over to your home every day, welcoming themselves in, and taking up space, getting in your way, without you being able to do anything about it.  You dont rent from a homeowner - a whole house or a bedroom - with the expectation that they will always be breathing down your neck, especially if they dont even live there with you.

Comment: Do you have a copy of the lease agreement?  If there is no lease agreement, it's a month-to-month rental.  Such a lease cannot be terminated without a 30-day notice given prior to an ending of any monthly period.  If she has no contractual right to enter the property (it's not in the lease), she entitled to 1 inspection of the inside of the property per year.  If you want to read through the relevant tenant-landlord laws, you can find them [here](https://app.leg.wa.gov/RCW/default.aspx?cite=59.18).

Answer (score 5):

> renting a single room with three other guys each renting their own rooms

means exactly what it says.
What you are paying for is that room, plus shared access to the common areas.

Without knowing exactly what your lease says, especially with respect to the common areas, it's difficult to give a proper answer.

I suspect that the lease for your room says nothing about who can live in the other rooms.
Unless the lease says otherwise, the landlord has full control of the common areas.
(Compare with a large apartment building, with hallways, stairwells, lobbies, etc., which must be maintained by the landlord.)

This isn't an unusual arrangement, but I've never understood why anyone, landlord or tenant, would want it.
There's far too much potential for conflict.

You, yourself, could be a totally obnoxious person that the other three guys can't stand, but they'd have to put up with you.
Their only alternatives are to move out or to ask the landlord to evict you.

Moving out would be a lot of trouble for everyone.
But, depending upon jurisdiction, as long as you're paying the rent on time and not causing damage to the property, eviction could be a very difficult and long process.

And eviction is hardly in the landlord's interest.
It costs a lot of money and time, and might not be granted even if she did apply.

> Why might a landlord spend so much time at the house they're renting?

I'd be concerned about the implications of a woman going out of her way to do yoga in an area rented to four men.
That is the part that sounds most strange in this situation.

> How do I resolve this?

I'd start looking for a room somewhere else.

Comment: I believe the moratorium on evictions is still in effect in the state of WA.  As such, even an attempt to establish a payment plan for backpayments (and certainly being up to date on rent) amount to defense.

Comment: There is not nearly enough reason here to start looking somewhere else.  Some people have boundary problems and do not realize what the expected boundaries are until they are informed.  Simply letting the person know that you expect to be left alone in exchange for the payment they receive may very well be enough.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there anything I can do?

There is no information on the terms of your contract.

Your perception that "*the landlord bas breached contract by treating us this way*" seems plausible, but you might be confusing between landlord's annoying habits and a plain breach of contract. The fact that other tenants have "*been here for significantly longer*" apparently without bring up these issues tends to weaken an allegation of landlord's wrongdoing. This is why knowing the terms of the contract is crucial for ascertaining whether the landlord has materially breached the contract. From a legal standpoint, the terms of the contract supersede parties' perceptions.

Many of the disturbances you describe sound in landlord's interference with your *quiet enjoyment* of the [dwelling unit](https://app.leg.wa.gov/RCW/default.aspx?cite=59.18.030) you rent. Likewise, her consumption of utilities you tenants pay sounds in *unjust enrichment* (or its equivalent term for *benefits in kind*). However, your willingness to breach the lease seems to be a premature decision. The landlord could easily prevail by positing that your allegations of annoyance were a mere pretext insofar as you did not even attempt to resolve these issues with her.

Regardless of whether you decide to post a *separate* question with details of the contract, make sure that henceforth your interactions with the landlord in this regard are *in writing*. That will make it easier for you to prove your arguments in the event that the matter ends up in court.

Comment: My roommates actually do complain about the behavior as well. They are just pacifists who let themselves get walked on, and who arent willing to take it to the next level.  I dont know if Id have their support, but I can get them on audiotape.

Comment: Appreciate the info and advice.

Comment: Also I do know the terms of my contract.  There is no mention of granting her these permissions. But there is no mention of depriving her of them either. She owns the place, and Im renting a room... with access and privilege to use the rest of the house.  However its clear she does not legally reside here yet spends 20% of her time here.

Comment: @SquishyRhode If/when you take this to court, you will need co-tenants' testimony to be in the form of affidavits, deposition, or testimony at trial rather than audiotape. Although the contract does not address these issues *explicitly*, it might contain language that *implicitly* favors your position. The more your position can be premised on the terms of the contract, the better.

Comment: My brother suggested that she may be committing some sort of fraud with the state.

Comment: @SquishyRhode "*My brother suggested that she may be committing some sort of fraud with the state*". Based on the information given so far, that belief is very inaccurate. The state has nothing to do with it. Even if the state had any involvement (for instance, in the form of a subsidies program), that could be totally unrelated to your matter.